# Custom authorize attribute with windows authentication and identity empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication, authorize-attribute

I create own implementation of authorize attribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Log4net logger
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        logger.Info("User name IsAuthenticated " + httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
        logger.Info("User name " + httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpContext.User.Identity.Name))
            {
                logger.Info("User name " + httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                string[] domainUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');
                if (domainUser.Count() == 2)
                {
                    if (domainUser[0].Equals("MyDomain", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        LdapService ldap = new LdapService();
                        return ldap.IsUserInAd(domainUser[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

and set this attribute for controller:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Log4net logger
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    /// <summary>
    /// Index method run on start of the Account view.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Action Result.</returns>
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        WindowsIdentity identity = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
        logger.Info("User name IsAuthenticated " + identity.IsAuthenticated);
        logger.Info("User name " + identity.Name);
        if (identity != null)
        {
            LdapService ldap = new LdapService();
            string[] domainUser = identity.Name.Split('\\');
            if (domainUser[1].Equals(AccessHelper.ReceptionUserName))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Guest");
            }
            else
                if (ldap.IsUserInReception(domainUser[1]))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Reception");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
                }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }
```

in web config I set windows auth...:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
     <identity impersonate="true" />
```

When I deploy my Asp.net mvc 4 app for server iis and run I have logged that I am not authenticated and User is empty. Why my page not see that I should be auth by windows credentials ?

Comment: Why would you use ldapservice with a Windows based application?

Answer (score 2):

Disable anonymous authentication in IIS on the server.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer at all. I downvoted because you didn't even explain yourself.